# Working with string streams?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

Say i have a stringsteam in C++, and I want to do different operations to it like:

Searching for a sequence of characters,
Converting block of text into int (in the middle of the line),
Moving the get pointer back and forth and so on.

What is the standard/common way of doing this kind of things with stringstreams?

Comment: Read this article [The Standard Librarian: Stringstreams and Their Friends](http://www.ddj.com/database/184403775).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use stringstream::str() method which returns the associated std::string object. Then you can do your desired operations on the returned string.

Answer (score 3):

As the name is saying, stringtream is a stream. A stream allows for sequential access, not random access. If you want random access, you can use the stringstream::str() function to get the string version of the string.